# Image-processing in python: input of photos with many sperm/egg cells and need to find the area of the cells

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I am working on a project with a Bio lab, which has thousands of images of cells (sperm and egg) taken from a microscope. My job is to automate a process to count cells in each image and record their area. I have done some research into sobel/canny edge detection, but am not sure the best way to pick out/separate cells. I am coding in Python 2.7 and using PIL/maybe openCV. any advice for where to start?

The following picture has had sobel edge detection run on it. Other images I am processing are similar. As you can see, there are still a lot of extra shapes in the background.

## Sobel Edge Detected Image

[image]

## Original Image

[image: Here is the picture before sobel detection]

Comment: Please also post original starting image and disclose your Operating System.

Comment: to remove most of the background I'd suggest thresholding

Comment: You may also want to look into OpenCV-Python for a lot of the image processing stuff

Comment: why is your resolution so low?